# Connecting Thunderbolt 2 device to 2010 Mac Pro

Tags: usb, thunderbolt

I have a Pegasus RAID array that connects to Thunderbolt 2 ports. I'm looking for a way to hook this up over USB 3 to my Mac Pro.

Does anyone have any suggestions? There is for example this: http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter

But I don't know if it would work since it would not be connected to a host device.

Thanks!
K.

Comment: are we sure we mean a Mac Pro... which already has Thunderbolt 2, but not USB-C... or are we confusing a Mac Pro with a MacBook Pro??

Comment: Aah! Sorry ment the old (real) Mac Pro. No thunderbolt available...

Comment: You cannot connect a TB device over USB 3.  TB1 and 2 is basically PCIe, DP, and power on a single connection.  USB is...well, USB.  If you need external storage at a decent speed, go with Fibre Channel because TB simply won't work.

Comment: We still need to know **which** Mac Pro. There were 6 - 5 of which cannot do Thunderbolt, nor can they be upgraded to; the 6th has it built-in, native,. & also USB3, but not USB-C

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the Promise Pegasus R4/R6 RAID directly to any 2013 Mac Pro.

You will need, however, a Thunderbolt 2 cable. These cables need to be bought separately and cost about about $35.

I have a Pegasus R4 RAID myself and can connect it to other Macs using the Thunderbolt cable without any issues. Keep in mind that you cannot connect two Macs simultaneously to the same Pegasus RAID.